# Rails 5 - Migrate to using UUID as primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Rails 5 allows the use UUIDs as primary keys.  I've recently migrated from Rails 4 to 5 and would like to utilise this functionality.  My current table has both UUID and serial id:

**schema.rb:**

```
create_table "customers", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.uuid "uuid", default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, null: false
    # other stuff...
end
```

What would migration look like to get rid of id and set uuid as primary key?

Comment: Do you have foreign keys on other tables that are pointing to `users.id` (aka: `belongs_to :user`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you already have id fields as integers and primary key. You have uuid field too. You can do something like

```
  def change
    change_table :customers do |t|
      t.remove :id
      t.rename :uuid, :id
    end

    execute 'ALTER TABLE brands ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);'
  end
```